# Apache2 starts only with sudo

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I have this problem that apache2 will only start when I call it with `sudo`. The main problem is that all the process are running as `root` and I don't like that.

I get the following error when doing:

```
$ service apache2 start
(13)Permission denied: apache2: could not open error log file /var/log/apache2/error.log.
```

If I check `envvars` I have it as:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
# Only /var/log/apache2 is handled by /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
```

And the permissions of the `/var/log/apache2` directory:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 root  root        4096 Jan  4 07:57 apache2
```

I tried to `chown` the folder to `www-data:www-data` and `www-data:root` without success. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try better to

> sudo adduser yourlogin www-data

or in /etc/apache2/envars:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=yourlogin
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=yourlogin
```

But doing that kind of things with Apache is rather painfull and is easier with nginx

Comment: first suggestion is to add yourself in www-data group but not sure it's enough so you could try second way

Comment: Thanks Gerard but I still get the same error after trying the first suggestion. I don't have access to `/var/log/apache2` unless I `sudo` it.

Comment: For /var/log/apache2/error.log you can choose a path of your choice in Apache conf changing: ErrorLog "/custom/dir/error.log"